# Вывод дива под ссылку

Tags: jquery, html, css

Здравствуйте. Как можно сделать с помощью jQuery вывод дива под видео? Например, при клике на ссылку открывалось див с видео под ссылку.
Сделал так, но див повторяется

```
$('.fik').hide();
var collection = $('.pm-thumb-fix.pm-thumb-145');

$(collection).click(function(){

$(".fik").slideToggle();
var url=$(this).attr('href');

$('.fik').load(url);
return false;
```

Спасибо за внимание

Comment: Оформите на http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/whHWs/

Comment: @fikos Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined 

оформите нормально на jsfiddle

Comment: @eicto это кусок со скрипта(phpmelody) . Нормально не будет работать на jsfiddle

Comment: Хотел сделать похожим вывод как (vube.com)